# Is there a plugin for eclipse to examine 2D arrays while debugging?

Tags: arrays, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin

I'm looking for a plug-in which displays a 2D array as a table while debugging. It will be great if it allows:

- scrolling
- searching
- assigning different fg/bg colors to different values

Currently I'm using a utility class whose toString method returns a string like:

```
0[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1[ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
2[ 0, 0 ...
```

so while debugging in eclipse I can create an expression like :

```
new Array2Dformatter(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you need this for? I think your solution is the best, but you should consider using the debug tools provided to you by Eclipse.

Is this for java?

Comment: Yes, it is for Java. Which debug tools do you mean?

Comment: @danyim This is quickest and simplest!

Answer (score 1):

Cool idea..

I usually do the following. I use the Eclipse Debug tools, like the Variables view, Inspect option and Display view. To get what you want try this one out. During debug, go to the Variables view, right click the variable and select New Detail Formatter...

Do that and you can display your array in the Variable view in the way you want (you need to put your toString() code here). Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

I have enhanced my utility class which now pops up a Jframe and does every trick I want. Best things is when code is stopped by a break point jframe continues responding. But I still prefer it to be part of eclipse not a class that I have to copy to every project.

Comment: if you already have a Java class written that does everything you want, it's not a big deal to wrap that class in an Eclipse plug-in.  How do you pass the array to the class?  A method call?  You'd have to figure out how to get the array into your plug-in, but otherwise, making a plug-in from a Java class is straightforward.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a method call. When I have some time I'll look for plug-in development. If I do it, it will be definitely open sourced so everyone will enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click wrap text, and resize the window so that it matches with column size of array